# Debug assertion failed, Expression: (unsigned)(c + 1) <=256 Ask Question c++

Tags: c++, for-loop, visual-c++, c-strings, isspace

I want to count the number of spaces. As I understand it, compiler sweare at this line **isspace(s[step]) != 0**. But sometimes the code started and there was no error. I don't know why it is so.

```
char s[] = "So she was considering";

int number_space = 0, step = 0;
int length_string = strlen(s);

while(strlen(s) != step){
    if(isspace(s[step]) != 0){ 
        number_space++;
    }
step++;
}

cout << number_space;
```

Comment: Try `while ( step < length_string )` … Also, when the debug assertion message shows up, does it show in your code where it happens?

Comment: `char` is normally signed and the “ctype” functions require a non-negative argument (or `EOF`). Try casting the argument to `unsigned char`.

Comment: Unrelated, `std::count_if` solves most of this for you, just feed it a decent predicate function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write

```
if ( isspace( static_cast<unsigned char>( s[step] ) ) != 0 ){
```

or

```
if ( isspace( ( unsigned char )s[step] ) != 0 ){
```

Otherwise in general the expression s[step] can yield a negative value.

This code snippet

```
int number_space = 0, step = 0;
int length_string = strlen(s);

while(strlen(s) != step){
    if(isspace(s[step]) != 0){ 
        number_space++;
    }
step++;
}
```

can be rewritten more simpler

```
size_t number_space = 0;

for ( size_t i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++ )
{
    if ( isspace( static_cast<unsigned char>( s[i] ) ) )
    {
        number_space++;
    } 
}
```

That is there is no need to call `strlen` and moreover in the condition of the loop.